# Custom docs for feathers.js services with Swagger

Tags: swagger, feathersjs

I have configured Swagger within my Feather.js app and it automatically generates docs for *all* endpoints on each service. Now, some endpoints on some service I want to omit from being generated as docs, because I simply disallow these endpoints or have some hidden logic behind them, that does not allow `external` calls.

F.e. I have the following setup for the endpoints of my `/users/me` service:

```
before: {
    all: [authenticate('jwt')],
    find: [
      /*
       * We don't use an ID when calling `/users/me` like `/users/me/<id>`, and therefore Feathers understands the
       * incoming request as a `find` method instead of `get`, therefore we simply redirect it internally.
       */
      async context => {
        context.result = await context.service.get(context.params.user.id); // eslint-disable-line
        return context;
      }
    ],
    get: [
      iff(isProvider('external'), disallow()),
      includeGender()
    ],
    create: [disallow()],
    update: [setAuthenticatedUserId()],
    patch: [setAuthenticatedUserId()],
    remove: [setAuthenticatedUserId()]
  }
```

As you can see from the logic setup, I want to have the following docs generated:
[image]

I've followed [these docs](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-swagger#servicedocs) regarding `feathers-swagger`. I use the `schemasGenerator(service, model, modelName, schemas)` to generate docs for each service. Understandably this will generate the same schema of docs for each service. I tried adding custom stuff, as per the github module explanations, by either adding the `docs` object:

```
 service.docs = {
            ...service.docs,
            operations: {
              find: false,
              create: false
            }
          };
```

or adding a global `operations: { find: false, create: false }` object on the Swagger config.

The first option doesn't have an effect, and the second option applies it to all endpoints, which doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the 'ignore' option to exclude the end-points that you want to. You may either specify the 'tags' array or the 'paths' array.

```
app.configure(swagger({
  docsPath: '/api/docs',
  uiIndex: true,
  specs: {
    info: {
      title: 'API Docs',
      description: 'Rest APIs',
      version: '1.0.0',
    },
    schemes: ['http', 'https'],
  },
  ignore: {
    paths: [
      'users'
    ]
  }
}));
```

You can also ignore end-points from service level.

```
usersService.docs = {
    description: 'A service to manage users',
    definitions: {
      users: m2s(options.Model),
      'users_list': {
        type: 'array',
        items: { $ref: '#/definitions/users' }
      }
    },
    securities: ['find', 'get', 'update', 'patch', 'remove'],
    operations: {'create': false}
  };
```

[Get complete documentation for feathers-swagger here](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-swagger)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is broken, as doing this has no result at all. Same goes for adding query params. I've seen other answers where people are resorting to manually manipulating the resulting json object.